# Узнать название заголовка

Tags: qt, qt5

В `QTableView` находится таблица из базы данных.

Каким способом можно получить имя заголовка конкретного столбца?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
QAbstractItemModel* model = tableView->model();

QVariant v = model.headerData(0/*номер столбца, или строки*/, 
                              Qt::Horizontal /*или Qt::Vertical*/,
                              Qt::DisplayRole);

QString text = v.toString();
```

Обычно, чтобы получить текст ячейки используют роль Qt::DisplayRole